# Link to Merriam-Webster app with iPhone

Tags: iphone, safari

I installed Merriam-Webster Dictionary application in my iPhone.

I sometimes find an unknown word when I'm web-surfing on Safari app, and I want to do a long-press on that word to link to M-W Dictionary app to know the definition of that word.

Is there a way to link directly from Safari to M-W Dictionary app?

Comment: To confirm, you’re aware that this exists already within iOS - right? It doesn’t open MW but you can long press a word, and select “Look Up”.

Comment: @JBallin Yes, I'm aware that. I just wonder that there is a way. Because I can save my search list in MW, and also listen to the pronunciation.